# Failing to save file cs file in Cloud9

Tags: c#, mono, cloud9-ide

In the "Custom" workspace I've installed mono (form github) and trying to save File.cs file fails due to the massage (I've changed chmod to all):

> Blockquote
>       Failed saving file ! : Program.cs ERR: Error: EACCES, open '/home/ubuntu/workspace/Program.cs'
>   Blockquote

Comment: Could you check who owns the file and make sure it is ubuntu:ubuntu?

Comment: yes, ok, I've created it with sudo fish, hence - root, just changed chmode permissions , so it's ok now